# Set wallpaper from created Bitmap of selected color

Tags: android, bitmap

Works when I create bitmap with 1 pixel width and 1 pixel height

```
Bitmap bm = Bitmap.createBitmap(new int[]{0xFF000000}, 1, 1, Bitmap.Config.RGB_565);
```

but when I create larger bitmap like this one, it gives me **ArrayIndexOutOfBounds**

```
Bitmap bm = Bitmap.createBitmap(new int[]{0xFF000000}, 50, 100, Bitmap.Config.RGB_565);
```

I just need to create bitmap from selected color.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your first argument is array of colors and as follows from documentation -

> colors -  Array of Color used to initialize the pixels. This array must be at least as large as width * height.

So with this array you are setting color to each pixel.

Comment: You know, you are right. Sometimes the easiest way is the better.

Comment: So you can check this post as an answer if that satisfied your needs :)